# Share multiple rails servers by domain on my local network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns, local

I have two rails servers running on my machine by 3000 and 3001 ports.

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 application.local
127.0.0.1 login.application.local
```

I want to get access for this servers from another devices (example - from mobile). I can connect by one port by my machine ip address, like a `192.168.0.100:3000` or `192.168.0.100:3001`.

But if I need to redirect from server 1 to server 2 on mobile - I cannot do it, because redirect from `192.168.0.100:3000` works not there `192.168.0.100:3001`, but there `login.application.local:3001` and phone cannot connection by local domain from my machine.

Maybe have solutions to share my two rails servers by local W network? To get access from mobile by `application.local:3000` domain instead device IP? Or how to solve case, when I want to go from *ip:port* on my mobile devise to another *ip:port*?

Comment: `192.168.0.100` is a local network IP. Is your mobile on the same WiFi or do you try to connect from the mobile network to your home network via its public IP address?

Comment: @spickermann yes, I've try. But I have another problem - I need share local domains by my network to get access to both server by `domain.local:port`, instead 'ip:port'. Because by 'ip:port' on mobile devices I cannot get redirects/cookies/data/etc from my second server

Comment: Do you have an appropriate `/etc/hosts` file on your mobile phone?

Comment: @spickermann mobile phone - just for example, how I said. Other tablets,phones, TV's, ps4, etc. And what kind of nonsense? Hot I add `/etc/hosts` file to, again for example, to iPhone or ps4?

Answer (score -1):

you can use ngrok to get access to your localhost on other devices

```
https://ngrok.com/
```

Comment: How I said - I need access on one wifi point to all my servers by local domain, not by ip:port/ngrok/etc. Strictly inside the wifi network.